# Couldn't return data after findByCreate by setDoc (React JS + Firebase)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm implementing `findOrCreate` to return data created by `setDoc()` in Firestore + React JS. But it returns `undefined`.

> Promise[[Prototype]]: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"[[PromiseResult]]: undefined

```
...
async findOrCreate(name: string, email: string, profileURL: string, userId: string) {
  const doc = await getDoc(this.doc(userId))
  const data = doc.data()
  if (data !== undefined) return
  const newData = await setDoc(this.doc(userId), {
    name, email, profileURL
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log('data', data)
    return data
  })
  console.log('newData', newData)
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`setDoc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#setdoc) function just returns a `Promise<void>` and not document data. You can just `console.log(data)` as that's the data you are setting in document.

Comment: Thanks for answering it! I would like to get data from setDoc(). How can I get it?